# Minimal haskell (ghc) program installation (deployment without ghc/cabal)

Tags: haskell, deployment, static-linking, yesod

(My problem is about distribute binaries without haskell-platform, ghc, cabal, ...)

I need deploy a well cabal formed haskell application (a Yesod scaffolded) but I have disk space restrictions.

GHC size is about 1Gbytes, store all cabal source code, packages, etc... require more disk space, etc...

Obviously, haskell-platform, ghc, ... is about development (not deployment).

In my specific case I can generate

```
cabal clean && cabal configure && cabal build
```

and run succesfully (some like)

```
./dist/build/MyEntryPoint/MyEntryPoint arg arg arg
```

But, what about dependencies?, how move it to production environment? (together my *"dist"* compilation)

Can I put binary dependencies without cabal? How?

Thank you very much!

Comment: See: [Do GHC-compiled binaries require GHC or are they self-contained?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389948/do-ghc-compiled-binaries-require-ghc-or-are-they-self-contained)

Comment: Do you think that only checking ldd dependencies it will run? I'll try! :)

Comment: See also notes on binary size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115459/small-haskell-program-compiled-with-ghc-into-huge-binary

Comment: Yes! I had to reinstall my i686 to x86_64 microserver (cross compilation is hard to me) but It's work fine! Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, ghc uses static linking of the Haskell libraries. So the resulting binary is independent of the Haskell ecosystem. If your program does not need any data files, just copy the binary out from `./dist/build/MyEntryPoint/MyEntryPoint` to the host

If you also have data files (e.g templates, images, static html pages) that are referenced by the binary using the data path finding logic of Cabal, you can use `Setup copy` as follows (using happy as an example):

```
/tmp/happy-1.18.10 $ ./Setup configure
Warning: defaultUserHooks in Setup script is deprecated.
Configuring happy-1.18.10...
/tmp/happy-1.18.10 $ ./Setup build
Building happy-1.18.10...
Preprocessing executable 'happy' for happy-1.18.10...
[ 1 of 18] Compiling NameSet          ( src/NameSet.hs, dist/build/happy/happy-tmp/NameSet.o )
[..]
[18 of 18] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.lhs, dist/build/happy/happy-tmp/Main.o )
Linking dist/build/happy/happy ...
/tmp/happy-1.18.10 $ ./Setup copy --destdir=/tmp/to_be_deployed/
Installing executable(s) in /tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/bin
/tmp/happy-1.18.10 $ find /tmp/to_be_deployed
/tmp/to_be_deployed
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/bin
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/bin/happy
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/doc
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/doc/happy-1.18.10
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/doc/happy-1.18.10/LICENSE
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/GLR_Lib-ghc-debug
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/GLR_Lib-ghc
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/GLR_Lib
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/GLR_Base
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate-arrays-coerce-debug
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate-arrays-ghc-debug
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate-arrays-debug
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate-arrays-coerce
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate-arrays-ghc
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate-arrays
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate-coerce
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate-ghc
/tmp/to_be_deployed/usr/local/share/happy-1.18.10/HappyTemplate
/tmp/happy-1.18.10 $ rsync -rva /tmp/to_be_deployed/ production.host:/
[..]
```

If you do not want to install into `/usr/local` then pass the desired prefix to `Setup configure`.

This works well if the target host is otherwise similar (same versions of C libraries such as gmp and ffi installed). If you also need to statically link some C library, see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389948/do-ghc-compiled-binaries-require-ghc-or-are-they-self-contained) that hammar has linked in his comment.

Comment: "the resulting binary is independent of the Haskell ecosystem" Thank you! I'll try it!